# In a WPF TextBlock how do I layer two runs on top of one another, one being below the baseline

Tags: wpf, layout, text

I am producing a form for print on a FixedPage and would like to have something like like this:

[image: Target Document snippet]

This image was hacked out in MS Word, I'd rather have the hints (Name, Position, Organization, etc) directly underneath the underscore prompt/baseline.

So basically I want to overlay two runs in the same part of the text 'flow': the underscore at a normal height, and the 'hint' label below the baseline.

I would like the end result to have these properties:

- Both the line and hint should be part of the text flow -- if I change the wording of the paragraph it should relocate automatically.  I don't want fixed  position on the hint that are 'out of band' with the paragraph.
- It will be a TextWrapping="Wrap" TextBlock, so the line height needs to behave sensibly.  The next line should not collide with a hint, and it's OK that there's a pretty large gap between lines in areas that don't have a hint.

Is there any way to do this?  I can't think of a way to even get started with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own solution to this, and it's pretty easy to make it into a reusable control so I'll post it here.

It turns out that WPF is perfectly happy to have a layout control like `<Grid />` inline a block of text.  Once you can do that, it's easy to layer things however you want.

Create a simple control class where we can set the text

```
public class PromptWithLabel : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(PromptWithLabel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public PromptWithLabel()
    {
    }
}
```

And create this template for it (a line at the bottom of the grid and a block of text with a negative margin to push it below the line, both stacked in the same grid cell)

```
<Style BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:PromptWithLabel}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:PromptWithLabel">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Black" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="7pt" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" Margin="0 0 0 -12" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Finally, this control can be contained within a TextBlock, and you just have to set an appropriate LineHeight on your TextBlock.

I don't 100% understand the 'LineStackingStrategy' in the template, but if that's not there, the placement of the hint gets all fouled up as you adjust the parent TextBlock's LineHeight.

Final result:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="20" >
    I, <controls:PromptWithLabel Text="(NAME)" Width="190" />, 
    commenced my professional practice in the field of 
    <controls:PromptWithLabel Text="(DISCIPLINE)" Width="180" /> 
    on the <controls:PromptWithLabel Text="(DAY)" Width="40" /> day of
    <controls:PromptWithLabel Text="(MONTH)" Width="90" /> in the year
    <controls:PromptWithLabel Text="(YEAR)" Width="70" />.
</TextBlock>
```

[image]

This works well for signature/date lines as well.